# Plantuml no padding in rectangle

Tags: plantuml

Is there any way of removing the padding from a rectangle in plantuml?

I have tried the following:

```
rectangle "rect1" as A1 #line:transparent;back:transparent

rectangle "rect2" as A2 #line:transparent;back:transparent


A1 -- A2
```

in my final diagram I will replace the text with an image, so maybe there is a better for images in the first place?

I've tried

```
rectangle "rect1" as A1 #line:transparent;back:transparent;padding:0
```

and tried skinParams too, but couldn't get it to work in any way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padding settings are a work in progress as far as I can tell. See the discussion in the forum [here](https://forum.plantuml.net/3118/introduce-padding-setting?show=3118#q3118). There's official [documentation](https://plantuml.com/style-evolution#faebbd3c7bf835b5) that says padding can be styled, but it doesn't seem to work properly for class diagrams. This is a question for the forum of PlantUML.

That said, here's a result you might find useful:

```
@startuml images
<style>
classdiagram {
    linecolor red
    class {
        padding 0  <-- doesn't work
        linecolor green
        BackgroundColor yellow
    }
}
</style>

skinparam style strictuml
skinparam padding 0
hide empty members
class "<img:http://plantuml.com/logo3.png{scale=0.5}>" as c1 
class "<img:http://plantuml.com/logo3.png{scale=0.5}>" as c2
c1 - c2
@enduml
```

**I purposefully left the background color and line color so you can see the padding.** Just set them to transparent for best results.

Perhaps you can try using other elements in PlantUML (rectangle, component, package, etc.) to see if a setting of `padding 0` is respected.

[image: Sample image]